# Problem with strings.xml... can't pass R.string.foo as a CharSequence

Tags: java, android, charsequence

I'm running a `TabActivity`. In the following line:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("alltime").setIndicator(R.string.plots_allTime)
       .setContent(intent);
```

I get an error because `setIndicator()` expects a `CharSequence`. I'm not really sure how to fix this, because I should be able to pass a string into that parameter. I think the issue lies in the fact that the generated `R.java` initializes everything in the `strings.xml` file as `public static final int`. The setIndicator() method doesn't seem to like that too much. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("alltime").setIndicator(getString(R.string.plots_allTime))
.setContent(intent);
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to get a string corresponding to the ID from R.string: use context.getText, which returns a localized, styled CharSequence from the application's package's default string table:

```
setIndicator(context.getText(R.string.plots_allTime) )
```